# Mirror vertex group (topology) isn't mirroring properly!

Tags: weight-painting

I'm looking for any relatively easy way to copy over the weights. I believe I might be going mad and have missed out on a simple solution...

Whenever I try to mirror the vertex group after copying the vertex group it seems to take a line/segment of the weights when copying over to the other side as opposed to the whole damn thing?

Help is much appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried without enabling Topology mirror ?

Comment: Nope - just done that now and no luck :(

It seems that it's only managed to transfer a line of the weights from the front and back side of the model. 

Whenever I do it I receive the following message -  26 vertices mirrored, 2248 failed

Comment: Did you use a Mirror Modifier for the vertices and apply the Modifier and then [ make no futher addition or deletion or position changes of vertices]?.  Life is easier when you reduce mesh changes.  I do not know the exact rules for mirror paint success.

Comment: Nope I didn't use the mirror modifier at all - I just copied and scaled/flipped it. I might just paint the other leg weights in, although it would be nice to know if there is a solution!

I'm more familiar with 3DS/Maya when it comes to stuff like this! I thought that its also important to learn Blender but damn it can be difficult to get my head around :(

Comment: And you did parent the armature with weights?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions

- Inspect and Correct armature names. Make sure your armature has names such as

  - Hand.R and Hand.L  .
- Copy the file for archive purposes, or duplicate scene. 3 minutes or less.
- Edit to half body. Use Mirror Modifier Mesh. Make Perfect.
- Apply Mirror Modifier. Full Body is result.  This may be viewed a common workflow.
- Make no further changes to Body Mesh.
- Perform quick and massive paint tests to see if new Body is weight paint friendly.

Comment: I have a feeling that it might not be perfectly symmetrical - I'll give this a try and let you know if it's done! Thanks everyone x

Comment: You are the Artist.  Half Body to Full Body is trying to guarantee symmetry.  I see the armature which can change position.  Perhaps this a 5 minute (discardable rubbish) learning experience.